# Ubuntu server 18.04 raid1 mdadm v4.0 Как включить дефрагментированную загрузку, опцию BOOT-DEGRADED

Tags: linux, ubuntu, raid

На одном диске установлен Ubuntu server 18.04 lts на двух других тестовый raid1.
При физическом удалении одного винта ждет 1,30 мин и вываливается в initramfs.

Делал как в этой [инструкции](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/advanced-installation).

Не получилось.
В этой [статье](https://ubuntu.fliplinux.com/32397.html) написано о проблеме ubuntu 16.04 lts.

Также в этой инструкции была подобная проблема  для ubuntu 16.04 lts для версии  mdadm 3.3-2ubuntu7 и исправлена ​​в 3.4-2.
Может быть в новой версии Mdadm 4.0  есть какое то более простое решение?

Воспользовался советом из статьи пункт 2
добавил команды для трех раид массивов в файл.
проверил работает.

> создайте новый файл: /etc/initramfs-tools/scripts/local-top/mdadm (не
> забудьте установить + x)
>
> добавьте следующий (массив принудительного запуска, если у вас есть
> /dev/md0 /dev/md1 /dev/md2
>
> mdadm –run /dev/md0
>
> mdadm –run /dev/md1
> mdadm –run /dev/md2
>
> тогда
>
> update-initramfs -k all -u , тогда вы все настроены.